# Netbeans Error when running a simple c program

Tags: c, netbeans

If I manually compile the code below, I got no error:

```
/* 
 * File:   newmain.c
 * Author: Mike
 *
 * Created on September 18, 2015, 7:36 PM
 */

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/*
 * 
 */
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    printf ("Hello!");
    return 0;
}
```

However, by doing the with NetBeans, I got the following error:

```
"/usr/bin/make" -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk QMAKE= SUBPROJECTS= .build-conf
make[1]: Entering directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/Mike/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_1'
"/usr/bin/make"  -f nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk dist/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/cppapplication_1.exe
make[2]: Entering directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/Mike/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_1'
mkdir -p build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows
rm -f "build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/newmain.o.d"
gcc    -c -g -MMD -MP -MF "build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/newmain.o.d" -o build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/newmain.o newmain.c
mkdir -p dist/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows
g++     -o dist/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/cppapplication_1 build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/main.o build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/newmain.o 
build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/newmain.o: In function `main':
/cygdrive/c/Users/Mike/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_1/newmain.c:14: multiple definition of `main'
build/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/main.o:/cygdrive/c/Users/Mike/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_1/main.cpp:15: first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk:63: recipe for target 'dist/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/cppapplication_1.exe' failed
make[2]: *** [dist/Debug/Cygwin_4.x-Windows/cppapplication_1.exe] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/Mike/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_1'
nbproject/Makefile-Debug.mk:60: recipe for target '.build-conf' failed
make[1]: *** [.build-conf] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/cygdrive/c/Users/Mike/Documents/NetBeansProjects/CppApplication_1'
nbproject/Makefile-impl.mk:39: recipe for target '.build-impl' failed
make: *** [.build-impl] Error 2

BUILD FAILED (exit value 2, total time: 1s)
```

How can I get this code being executed in the NetBeans too?

Comment: NetBeans is complaining about multiple definitions of `main`, one in `newmain.c` and another in `main.cpp`.  Did you create a C++ project by mistake that automatically creates a `main` for you?

Comment: You are right! But now I get a "Unable to start pty process:" "RUN FAILED (exit value -2, total...)"